# grep command in cygwin can't use chinese character

Tags: cygwin

I find that the grep command in cygwin  can't  use chinese characters, how can i fix this?

I create a file named test.txt, which contains a chinese character "圣诞节"  (meaning of christmas).

```
grep   "圣诞节"  /cygdrive/c/*
```

nothing happens, and the file will not be searched.

my problem is that chinese character can be displayed on my screen ,and chinese character can be inputted into cgywin console ,and  i can search chinese character with grep,but can not get right result with `grep   "圣诞节"  /cygdrive/c/*`.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this link](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-locale.html) from Cygwin on setting up your locale. From there, you ***may*** be able to use Unicode characters with Cygwin utilities, but I haven't tested it to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

the phenomenon  vanish after my reinstallation of vim .